# Why my array doesn't print different subjects name inputted by a user?

Tags: c++, arrays, storage

The objective is to take input of subjects and their marks from a user and finally display them as a report card. Everything works as expected except that the compiler prints the name of the last subject entered for each different subject name in the final report.

**Here is the C++ code that I tried:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string fname, lname;
    int subjects;
    float totalMarks;
    cout << "Enter your first name: ";
    cin >> fname;
    cout << "Enter your last name: ";
    cin >> lname;
    cout << "Enter total marks: ";
    cin >> totalMarks;
    cout << "Marks of how many subjects: ";
    cin >> subjects;
    float subjectMarks[subjects];
    string subjectNames[subjects];
    for (int i = 0; i < subjects; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < subjects; j++) {
                cout << "Enter name of subject: ";
                cin >> subjectNames[j];
                break; // I've used 'break' to exit the inner loop and go to outer loop for
                       // entering the marks obtained in the subject
                };
            cout << "Enter marks obtained in the subject: ";
            cin >> subjectMarks[i];
    };

    cout << "Dear, " << fname << " " << lname << "! The subjects and their marks are shown below: \n";
    cout << "RESULTS IN SUBJECTS\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < subjects; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < subjects; j++) {
            cout << subjectNames[j] << "\t\t";
            break;
        }
        cout << subjectMarks[i] << endl;
    };

return 0;
}
```

**What I expected?**

As you can see in the screenshot, 'Chemistry' is printed twice with different marks. It should have printed first 'Physics' with marks '80' and then 'Chemistry' with marks '70' as inputted by the user. I doubt there is a problem with ***subjectNames[]*** array.

**But this is what actually happened**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Mat.png)

I'm stuck on this problem for more than 3 hours. Please help!

Comment: The `break` s are misplaced. It'll restart the inner loop for every iteration of the outer loops. You only need one loop to read and one to print.

Comment: Take a piece of pen of paper or launch a debugger and note down what will be values of `i` and `j` in your loops at every iteration. Then think why are there two nested loops at all.

Comment: c++ does not support defining arrays with runtime values as their dimensions - use a vector. and perhaps you would not be stuck if you had read a decent c++ textbook

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: `int subjects;...float subjectMarks[subjects]; string subjectNames[subjects];` -- [This is not valid C++ code.](https://godbolt.org/z/5ndGxTGGT)

Answer (score 1):

The loop for reading and the loop for writing is wrong. You don't need nested loops. Just have one variable when reading and one when writing:

```cpp
// reading
for (int i = 0; i < subjects; i++) {
    std::cout << "Enter name of subject: ";
    std::cin >> subjectNames[i];
    std::cout << "Enter marks obtained in the subject: ";
    std::cin >> subjectMarks[i];
};
```

```cpp
// writing
std::cout << "Dear, " << fname << " " << lname
          << "! The subjects and their marks are shown below:\n"
             "RESULTS IN SUBJECTS\n\n";
for (int i = 0; i < subjects; i++) {
    std::cout << subjectNames[i] << "\t\t"
              << subjectMarks[i] << '\n';
}
```

Also note that your `subjectMarks` and `subjectNames` are Variable Length Arrays (VLAs) and those aren't supported in standard C++. Only some compilers supports them as an extension. I recommend that you use `std::vector`s instead:

```cpp
#include <vector>

// ...

std::vector<float> subjectMarks(subjects);
std::vector<std::string> subjectNames(subjects);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Lyngmo. You just cleared my doubt. When you said, "You don't need nested loops." I got it. Thanks again.